# How to pass values in url on pagination links in cakephp

Tags: pagination, cakephp-2.1

This is my pagination link:

```
<div class="paging" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
    <div class="paging_right" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
    <?php echo $this->paginator->prev('<< '.__('previous', true), array('url'=>array('action'=>'ViewMember/ticket')), null, array('class'=>'disabled'));?>
    |<?php echo $this->paginator->numbers(array('url'=>array('action'=>'ViewMember/ticket'),'pagecnt'=>$ticketcount,'pagenum'=>$pagenumticket));?>  
    <?php echo $this->paginator->next(__('next', true).' >>', array('url'=>array('action'=>'ViewMember/ticket')), null, array('class'=>'disabled'));?>          
    </div>
    </div>
```

This it the url when click on links:

```
http://localhost/mysite/TestController/ViewMember/ticket/page:2
```

But i want to the url like this:

```
http://localhost/mysite/TestController/ViewMember/ticket/page:2/#tinfo
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Can anyone get idea.........?

Comment: Explain why you want a hash tag on the end of your URL...